# Paste tool for OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, command-line, copy-paste

There is paste tool in Linux but have not found for OSX. 
Its name was probably dpaste or something in Linux.

Assume you run `xxd -ps r328.raw |  head -n2430` and you want to paste it to your friend. 
It will be difficult to paste it to him. 
Of course, I can store it into file but I want to get it to my clipboard.

How can you get paste thing to your clipboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**man pbcopy**

```
pbcopy  takes  the  standard input and places it in the specified
pasteboard. If no pasteboard is specified, the general pasteboard
will be used by default. The input is placed in the pasteboard as
plain  text data unless it begins with the Encapsulated PostScript (EPS)
file header or the Rich Text Format (RTF) file header, in which case
it is placed in the pasteboard as one of those data types
```

So

```
xxd -ps r328.raw |  head -n2430 | pbcopy
```

should place the output in the clipboard